# Vue2+Foundation, Getting error in their integration

Tags: vue.js, zurb-foundation

I am integrating Vue2 and Foundation-sites, I keep getting this error Refused to load the font 'https://sxt.cdn.skype.com/assets/fonts/SkypeAssets-Regular.woff' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self'". Note that 'font-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem while using bootstrap. Adding the following to `webpack.base.conf.js` resolved the issue

```
{ 
    test: /\.(png|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, 
    loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000' 
}
```

I found out about the solution from [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/38) though the original issue there is slightly different.